# Asp.Net Core 2.1 SPA React Template with Windows Authentication

Tags: c#, iis, windows-authentication, asp.net-core-2.1

When I use Windows Authentication in my debug environment(IIS Express), I get the proper domain name. But when I push it to the production environment(IIS), I get no domain name at all. Am I missing something?

Reproduce my Issue:

I've created a new Web Project in VS2017 (15.7.6) with the React template and enabled Windows authentication by changing the launchSettings.json to:

```
"windowsAuthentication": true,
"anonymousAuthentication": false,
```

Now I changed the `ConfigureServices` Method in `Startup.cs` to this:

```cs
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services) 
{
    services.Configure<IISOptions>(options =>
    {
        options.AutomaticAuthentication = true;
    });
    services.AddAuthentication(IISDefaults.AuthenticationScheme);

    var names = new[] { "peter", "joey" };


    services.AddAuthorization(options =>
    {
        options.AddPolicy("OnlyEmployees", policy =>
        {
            policy.AddAuthenticationSchemes(IISDefaults.AuthenticationScheme);
            policy.Requirements.Add(new CheckForEmployee(names));
        });
    });
    services.AddSingleton<IAuthorizationHandler, CheckForEmployeeHandler>();

    services.AddMvc().SetCompatibilityVersion(CompatibilityVersion.Version_2_1);
    // In production, the React files will be served from this directory
    services.AddSpaStaticFiles(configuration =>
    {
        configuration.RootPath = "ClientApp/build";
    }); 
}
```

I added 2 Files to the Project:

CheckForEmployee.cs

```cs
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authorization;

namespace WebServer_WindowsAuthentication
{
    public class CheckForEmployee : IAuthorizationRequirement
    {
        public string[] Names { get; set; }
        public CheckForEmployee(string[] names)
        {
            Names = names;
        }
    }
}
```

CheckForEmployeeHandler.cs

```cs
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authorization;

namespace WebServer_WindowsAuthentication
{
    public class CheckForEmployeeHandler : AuthorizationHandler<CheckForEmployee>
    {
        protected override Task HandleRequirementAsync(AuthorizationHandlerContext context, CheckForEmployee requirement)
        {
            if (requirement.Names.Contains(context.User.Identity.Name))
            {
                context.Succeed(requirement);
            }

            return Task.CompletedTask;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: "For some reason this will only work locally." Then what's the question?

Comment: @LexLi I've updated the question, it should be more clear now.

Comment: Explain what is “ onto real IIS server it won't work”.

Comment: I already mentioned what is not working, but I'll clarify more. When I run the program locally (Visual Studio uses IIS Express) and I access my page (via localhost), I get the Proper Windows username with the internal active directory domain prepending. But when I deploy my project to a directory, where an IIS Service is configured to listen to and run the app on our Server when changes happen, and then access the web page online, I don't get any Windows authentication. In conclusion I am not receiving the Windows username when I access the page over the internet.

Comment: IIS Windows authentication is never recommended over the internet due to various security factors. Use forms based authentication or OAuth.

Comment: @LexLi I forgot to mention that this web page will be hosted in an intranet, so only emplyoees who are in the domain have access to the page, but I still need to authenticate them so I can limit the page to certain users in the domain.

Comment: It makes sense to host a site in intranet with Windows authentication. How did you configure IIS then? Did you enable Windows authentication on IIS, and also ask ASP.NET Core module to pass the Windows authentication token?

Comment: @LexLi I've tested this behavior with a template project, that should work from the get-go, I think Windows Authentication is not installed on the server. Could this be the cause for this issue? Because our sysadmin just recently installed the IIS-Service on our server. He may misconfigured something or didn't install this feature at all. Trying to get in touch with him and ask him if he could check on the Windows Authentication configuration.

Answer (score 0):

Anyone facing a similar problem, make sure Windows Authentication is enabled on your IIS Service. This solved my problem.